# How does bootstrap css target all class .table independent of parent/child?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

For example, if I use

```
<table class='table'></table>
```

and

```
<div> <table class='table'></table> </div>
```

both table tags will get the bootstrap .table stylings. But when I work with css, if I want to apply stylings to both, I have to use 2 different styling calls

```
.table{};

div .table{};
```

How does bootstrap do it?

Comment: That shouldn't be the case... Even if your class is surrounded by another element, `css` should still target it. Check this for example: http://www.bootply.com/ENgWr8kvnw

Comment: Ok, the link you provided works. I will not refuting that, however, when I write <style>
 
 .title {
  height: 1000px,
  width: 1000px,
  background-color: #000000;
 }

</style>

<div class='summary'>
 <div class='universals'>
  <div class='name universal-base'>
   <div class='title'>Name</div>
   <div class='universal-content'>
    16AA0001
   </div>
  </div>

etc...
the resulting page I see when opening it up in Chrome (vs 55) doesnt style it...

Comment: If you are using double quotes for class name, please make sure to add opening and closing quotes. Not in combination as written above :
<div> <table class='table"></table> </div>

Comment: above I used single quotes on both sides, ', sorry, I just wrote it incorrectly.

Comment: As @TimLewis says, `.table { /* styles */ }` should select all elements of any type, at any depth, regardless of parentage, so `<section><div> <p class="table">...</p></div></section>` as well as `<div class="table">` or `<table class="table">` — it's possible that other, more specific styles _override_ that rule.  Use your browser's DOM inspector to see the element and what styles are being applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you are saying **... if I want to apply stylings to both, I have to use 2 different styling calls** is not true.

See this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/pablodarde/ecxxcx3j/

If you set a class "table", all tables in your code will follow the class rules. However, if you specialize some tables, like, `div .table`, those tables will follow the `div .table` rules.

Try an experience, remove the `div .table` from css code.

The css engine start looking for the most specialized elements before, and keep looking until reach the most general rules.

**HTML**

```
<table class='table'>
  <tr>
    <td>T1 C1</td>
    <td>T1 C2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div>
  <table class='table'>
    <tr>
      <td>T2 C1</td>
      <td>T2 C2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <table class='table'>
        <tr>
          <td>T1 C1</td>
          <td>T1 C2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div .table {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```